# Lightdm doesn't show wallpaper/background and colors are wrong

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background, unity-greeter

The symptoms of the problem are that only default Ubuntu wallpaper is shown in the login screen, the password field, host name (in the top left corner) and menu (in the top right corner) have an ugly grey background and for example the date/time is hardly visible because it's black text on relatively dark default background.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has a far easier solution than what I first looked for:

**In the login screen**, **open the Accessibility menu** – one of the icons in the top right corner – and **disable High Contrast mode**. So it's not a bug, it's accidentally for example hitting the shortcut key to enable the High Contrast mode.

It's made more confusing by the fact/bug that it's not really well working as a high contrast mode since the mode does not fit well to the Ubuntu's / unity-greeter's default background. Another confusing element is the disappearance of the user background, which feels like a bug while actually it's probably designed to force correct high contrast text if some original Lightdm default background would be used instead of the Ubuntu background.